# Fetch third party data in a periodic interval

Tags: aws-lambda, architecture

I've an application with 10M users. The application has access to the user's Google Health data. I want to periodically read/refresh users' data using Google APIs.

The challenge that I'm facing is the `memory-intensive task`. Since Google does not provide any callback for new data, I'll be doing background sync (every 30 mins). All users would be picked and added to a queue, which would then be picked sequentially (depending upon the number of worker nodes).

Now for 10M users being refreshed every 30 mins, I need a lot of worker nodes.

```
Each user request takes around 1 sec including network calls.
In 30 mins, I can process = 1800 users
To process 10M users, I need 10M/1800 nodes = 5.5K nodes
```

**Quite expensive. Both monetary and operationally.**

Then thought of using lambdas. However, lambda requires a NAT with an internet gateway to access the public internet. Relatively, it very cheap.

Want to understand if there's any other possible solution wrt the scale?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about your architecture and the google APIs it is difficult to make a recommendation.

Firstly I would see if google offer a bulk export functionality, then batch up the user requests.  So instead of making 1 request per user you can make say 1 request for 100k users.  This would reduce the overhead associated with connecting and processing/parsing of the message metadata.

Secondly i'd look to see if i could reduce the processing time,  for example an interpreted language like python is in a lot of cases much slower than a compiled language like C# or GO.  Or maybe a library or algorithm can be replaced with something more optimal.

Without more details of your specific setup its hard to offer more specific advice.